# Cannot read value 'visibility' of undefined - J

Tags: javascript, jquery, visibility

I am using jQuery. Whenever the menu.tog function is called, it seems to forget what 'this' (menu) is. I have also tried replacing 'this' with 'menu' in the function.

```
    var usn = $("#userstuff");
var menu = $('#userinfo');

menu.height('0px');

menu.tog=function()
{
if (menu.css('visibility','hidden')=='hidden')
    menu.css('visibility','visible');
else
    menu.css('visibility','hidden');
}
```

Comment: FWIW using GNU-style brackets over K&R-style brackets and not using brackets on conditionals are both error-prone in JavaScript and generally a **bad idea**

Comment: @JaredSmith I appreciate the advice but if you could elaborate, I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: He means the brackets around the `if`. I've added them in my example.

Comment: @CLASSIFIED google is your friend, but short version: on the conditionals that only works if they're one-line. You *will* go back and add more stuff to a clause and you *will* create bugs by forgetting to add the braces. Speaking of braces, have them be at the *end* of the previous line rather than starting the block on a new line. Because of the way JS is  parsed it can lead to subtle bugs if you're not careful. There's certainly plenty of JS code in the wild with GNU braces, so it *can* be done, but the other way is less error-prone.

Comment: The google JavaScript style guide is actually a pretty good resource and far, far less controversial than some of their other ones (\*COUGH C++ \*COUGH).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
// only use 'menu', not '$(menu)' and don't write 'px'
// or in one row: var menu = $('#userinfo').height(0);
var menu = $('#userinfo');
menu.height(0);

// however your `tog` function is called, there may be not referenced
// to 'this', instead use 'menu'
// but keep in mind, 'menu' is a jQuery object here, not a DOM element
menu.tog = function() {
    if ( menu.css("visibility") == "hidden" ) {
        menu.css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    else {
        menu.css("visibility", "hidden");
    }

    // or in one line too:
    // menu.css("visibility", menu.css("visibility") == "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden");
};

menu.tog();
```

Comment: Now it says invalid left hand side in assignment. Note: it says this regardless of if i use `menu` or `this`

Comment: Is your `if` correct? Sounds like you have a single `=` there in your code.

Comment: I have changed the question to reflect what I have now.

Comment: use `menu.css("visibility", "visible");` and not `menu.css('visibility')='visible';`, and the same for `hidden` too. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to toggle visibility, just do this:

```js
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('#test').toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="test">TOGGLE ME</span>
</br>
<button id="toggle">CLICK TO TOGGLE</button>
```

Comment: I am using visibility because `hide()`, `show()`, and `toggle()` affect the `display` value.

Comment: I have put what I have in the original question. Is there something you could point out?

Answer (score 0):

To properly extend jquery use jQuery.fn.extend. Then when you reference this you will referencing the correct objects.

```
   jQuery.fn.extend({
     tog: function() {
       return this.each(function() {
           this.style.visibility = this.style.visibility == 'hidden' ? 'visible':'hidden';
       });
     }
   });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gkjhygoa/

Comment: I will hold this for future reference, it's really neat to know. However, I will not be using it in this case.